# Positioning inputfield in jade

Tags: html, css, pug

Trying to get a span that is a circle next to it a inputfield and next to that a button. This inside a div that has 50% and the div next to its floats left and is also 50% with an image inside.

[image]

This is the JADE file

```
section(class=spec.__class)&attributes(attributes)
      .row
        .options
            .left.first
                img(src='images/prijzen.png', alt='prijzen')
            .right 
                p. 
                    In onze Surprise Webshop is elk pakje gratis. Wat u precies heeft besteld, blijft wel een verrassing tot u het pakje ophaalt in een afhaalpunt of pakjesautomaat naar keuze.

                .row.clear
                        span.nr.bgred 1 

                    .row.rightfields

                        form.inputform(name="add-estimation", method="post")
                            .inputfielddiv.floatleft
                                input.styleds(type="text", name="title", placeholder="Vul hier uw persoonlijke code in")
                            .inputdiv.floatright
                                a.button.red.round.ctaright(type="submit", value=">", href="#kiespakje")
```

This is the CSS

```
 .row {
        @include center(1024px);
        margin-bottom: 4em;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 840px;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        .fix {
            clear: both;
        }
        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
        .inputdiv {
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-right: .5em;
        }
        .options {
            margin-top: 70px;
            .left {
                float: left;
                clear: none;
                text-align: inherit;
                width: 40%;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-right: 5%;
            }
            .left img{
                width: 340px;
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
            .right {
                padding: 0 20px;
                float: left;
                clear: none;
                text-align: inherit;
                width: 100%;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-right: 0%;
                border-left: 0;
                @include breakpoint($tablets) {
                    padding: 0 0 0 50px;;
                }
                .nr {
                    position: relative;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding-top: 15px;
                    width: 3em;
                    height: 3em;
                    display: inline-block;
                    border-radius: 100%;
                }
                .bgred {
                    background: #EF2637;
                    color: white;
                }
                .leftbol {
                    float: left;
                    width: 100%;
                }
                .rightfields {
                    width: 100%;
                    float: right;
                    display: inline-block;
                    .inputform {
                        width: 100%;
                        .floatleft {
                            width: 75%;
                            float: left;
                            @include breakpoint($tablets) {
                                width: 100%;
                            }
                            .styleds {
                                width: 100%;
                                padding: 0.8em;
                                margin-bottom: 1em;
                                border-radius: 0.2em;
                                -webkit-appearance: none;
                                -moz-appearance: none;
                                appearance: none;
                                box-shadow: none;
                                border: none;
                                color: black !important;
                                border-radius: 0;
                                background-color: #D5D5D5;
                                font-style: italic;
                            }
                        }
                        .floatright {
                            width: 20%;
                            float: right;
                            .buttoncode {
                                text-decoration: none;
                                border: none;
                                padding: 22px;
                                font-weight: bold;
                                font-size: 15px;
                                display: inline-block;
                                width: 100%;
                                max-width: 250px;
                                margin-top: 0 auto;
                                text-align: center;
                                color: white;
                                background-color: #EF2637;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .right p {
                text-align: center;
                margin-left: 0px;
                @include breakpoint($tablets) {
                    text-align: left;
                }
            }
            .right span{
                margin-left: 140px;
                @include breakpoint($tablets) {
                    margin-left: 0px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing in it...and can you show us running code?

Comment: @Gaurav Aggarwal can't realy show running code but the problem now is that on the first line is the span and underneath the inputfield and underneath that the button but they need to be on one line positioned with floats and width percentages

Comment: added an image of the problem